# check resistance is bigger then a constant?

Tags: resistance, low-power, detection

As a part of a bigger project, I want to build an high resistance  detector that will respond with a logical pulse
0- under `50KΩ`
1- more then `50KΩ`
what would be the most power efficient way of doing it?
I thought about using this one some how, but I'm stuck here.
 [image]

Comment: Do you have access to a small microcontroller such as an arduino? With a Uc, it would be possible to use the onboard voltage reference and the analog inputs to determine the resistance of something being probed.

Comment: Can the output be a level rather than a pulse?  If so a single comparator with a bridge as input is all you need.

Comment: @JayGreco since when are Arduinos small microcontrollers? He should use an 8-pin bare chip if any, no board needed.

Comment: I'm very sorry, the pulse can be a level, I suold have said that.
I can use a microcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a logical pulse, you might want to consider some type of circuit that changes state across a relatively fine boundary, so you can be as precise as possible.  For instance, you could create a simple voltage divider that is connected in series with your load, and put a BJT with the base connected between the voltage divider such that it turns on when the load is 50K Ohms.  Since a silicon BJT generally turns on at 0.7 volts, just select the values for your circuit to accomplish this based on your voltage input.  If your probe has a 5V input, you could stick a 300K Ohm in series and when the load rises to 50K, it will create a ratio of 0.14 (50/350) of the input voltage, or 0.714 volts at the divider, enough to turn on the BJT.  Of course this isn't extremely precise, but this is just one way.  This could also be done with zener diodes.

Granted this solution is not a pulse, it is a level output.

It could easily be made a pulse with a timer or a uC.  An ATTiny85 is only $2.

Comment: great answer! it think that would work wonderfully. because precision isn't a very big deal... that would work. Would you considered your solution as power saving?( in relevance to... @Jay Greco solution ?

Comment: @almog With a 5V probe, your circuit will consume a mere 14.2 uA upon reaching a 50K resistance.  (5/350,000).  The highest current it could consume would be 16.66 uA. (5/300,000)  I would say it's pretty power efficient. You could always current limit this lower if you'd like.